# MySQL sort by case when column value equal search value in where clause dynamic query

Tags: mysql

I have Table people like this

```
------------------------------------------------
|    id    |    full_name    |   first_name    |
------------------------------------------------
|     1    |     aaa bbb     |        aaa      |
|     2    |     bbb ccc     |        bbb      |
|     3    |     ddd aaa     |        ddd      |
|     4    |     aaa fff     |        aaa      |
|     5    |     aaa         |        aaa      |
------------------------------------------------
```

I try to search for aaa and then sort the result based on first name = where clause like this

```
SELECT `id`,`full_name`,`first_name` FROM `people`
WHERE `full_name` like '%aaa%'
Order by case 
when full_name = 'aaa' then 1
when first_name like '%aaa' then 2
else 3 end asc
```

so far so good for me what I want is not to set full_name = 'aaa' and first_name like '%aaa' in the order by case manually I want to tell MySQL something like this

```
Order by case 
when full_name = "what I searched for in my full_name where clause" then 1
when first_name like '%what I searched for in my full_name where clause' then 2
else 3 end asc
```

```
--
-- Table structure for table `people`
--

CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

--
-- Dumping data for table `people`
--

INSERT INTO `people` (`id`, `full_name`, `first_name`) VALUES
(1, 'aaa bbb', 'aaa'),
(2, 'bbb ccc', 'bbb'),
(3, 'ddd aaa', 'ddd'),
(4, 'aaa fff', 'aaa'),
(5, 'aaa', 'aaa');
```

Edit
assuming that I can only write aaa in the query part WHERE full_name like '%aaa%' is there any way to read it from the where clause without a procedure or setting variable to pass it to the order by case

Comment: I don't understand the difference between what you have and what you want in your ORDER BY, they look the same

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also not clear why the where condition the `=` is on the `full_name` and the `like` on the `first_name` when looks like should be the other way around. And seem the `like` should be `aaa%` not `%aaa`. Bottom line show us your current and your desire result

Comment: the condition = on the full_name so if the full name aaa he is first - and you are correct it should be %aaa - the query work as I want it I want to make it dynamic query and assuming  that I can only write it in the part WHERE `full_name` like '%aaa%' is there any way to read it from the where clause without a procedure or setting variable

Comment: Why cant use procedures or at least use one user variable?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and then use `%` as an escape character to check if your input string contains `%` sign. Based on that, you can change what column you `ORDER BY`.

I present an example below.

```
SET @input_str1:='%abc%';
SET @input_str2:='abc';

SELECT
  @input_str1,
  @input_str2,
  CASE WHEN @input_str1 LIKE '%|%%' escape '|' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END order_by_1,
  CASE WHEN @input_str2 LIKE '%|%%' escape '|' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END order_by_2
;
```

I have defined two strings `input_str1` that contains `%` and `input_str2` that does not contain the `%` symbol. Then, in my select query, I select:

- `input_str1` as first column
- `input_str2` as the second column
- the third column contains `1` if the `input_str1` contains `%` otherwise `0`
- the fourth column contains `1` if the `input_str2` contains `%` otherwise `0`

Therefore, the output is:

```
%abc%      abc      1       0
```

If you want to order by based on which matches you find (which isn't entirely clear, but I suspect is what you're trying to do), then you can similarly create multiple flags and use those to decide what to order by.

Alternatively, if you just want to determine the order based on what your input string is, using the concept I showed above, you can create another user-defined variable `order_by_column` based on whether your input string contains `%` symbol or not.

```
SET @order_by_column =  CASE WHEN @input_str LIKE '%|%%' escape '|' THEN 'first_name' ELSE 'full_name' END;
```

.. and then use the determined `@order_by_column` to order your results.

Comment: assuming that I can only write aaa in the query part WHERE full_name like '%aaa%' is there any way to read it from the where clause without a procedure or setting variable to pass it to the order by case

Comment: You should explain why can only write the where but not the order by.

Comment: in the application user will search for aaa - the site owner notice that there are a problem in the sort order its done full_name like '%aaa%' order by full_name asc or desc - the owner have no source code but in site admin panel the ability to just write the order by query by hand so I change it to : order by case when full_name = 'aaa' then 1 when first_name like '%aaa' then 2 else 3 end asc - that will do correct sorting and fix the problem if its writing manually and for just searching of aaa but the user can search for anything thats why I want to be able to make the query dynamic

Comment: @MichaelShams you can create one column each, for each type of match that you want to do. You can simple use the input string where checking for equality and concatenate it with `%` where you check using the `LIKE` operator, and then you can order by whichever of these columns has a value set.

I think it's really just that you need consider which conditions to evaluate (maybe, even why) and then the simplest solution would work the best.

Comment: @MichaelShams I just read your recent comment about the use-case, and I think a totally different approach is required. If I understood your comment correctly, you need to order by first name if the user is searching for first name, and order by full name if the user is searching for the full name. I could be wrong in my understanding, but if this is indeed the case, then the correct approach would be to let user also specify what he's search by. If the user doesn't know the query that's running underneath & what they're searching for, then you should order by any column you think is the best.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is you don't want to change the `aaa` part three times if need change the search parameter.

create a procedure and use a dynamic query.

```
create procedure sort(search varchar(15))
begin
    set @s := 
    concat( 'SELECT `id`,`full_name`,`first_name` FROM `people`',
            'WHERE `full_name` like \'%', search, '%\' ',
            'Order by case ', 
            'when full_name = \'', search, '\' then 1 '
            'when first_name like \'%' , search, '\' then 2'
            'else 3 end asc');

    prepare query from @s;
    execute query;
    deallocate prepare query;
end$$
```

Comment: assuming  that I can only write it in the part WHERE `full_name` like '%aaa%' is there any way to read it from the where clause without a procedure or setting variable

Comment: Now you are just been lazy :P. I dont think you can do that.

Comment: I swear I am not trying to be lazy I spent the whole day trying to make it work with no hope stackoverflow was my last stop - the query is part of application that do search with a lot of parameter and I only have access to modify the order by part of the query so I change it to order by case and I want to read the full_name like clause to make it work

Comment: Well Im not sure what is the problem that is why seem lazy. If you can change the where part why cant change the  order part? I thought was a problem of avoid repetition and there for suggest create a procedure for it

Comment: in the application user will search for aaa - the site owner notice that there are a problem in the sort order its done full_name like '%aaa%' order by full_name asc or desc - the owner have no source code but in site admin panel the ability to just write the order by query by hand so I change it to  : order by case when full_name = 'aaa' then 1 when first_name like '%aaa' then 2 else 3 end asc - that will do correct sorting and fix the problem if its writing manually and for just searching of aaa but the user can search for anything thats why I want to be able to make the query dynamic

Comment: I see. But Im sorry to say dont think you can do anything like that without using variables. Maybe you can include that description as part of the question. The context sometimes help to solve the problems